# Knockoutjs Validation issue - self.errors().length

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have included :

knockout.3.0.1.js

knockout.validation.debug.js

jquery.validate.js

**Error is :** (From Firebug)

```
TypeError: self.errors is not a function
```

Except validation all other code is perfect.

**My Code**

```
var UserViewModel = function (UserName, Password) {
    var self = this;

    self.UserName = ko.observable(UserName).extend({
        required: {
            message:"Please enter User Name"
        }
    });
    self.Password = ko.observable(Password).extend({
        required: {
            message: "Please enter Password"
        }
    });


    this.loginClick = function () {

        if (self.errors().length == 0)
        {
            alert('no errors');
          //  var strJSON = ko.toJSON(self); //Convert whole model to json
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please check your submission");
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
        alert("function called");

    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel('', ''));
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle, it is obvious that the error property isn't presented in self scope

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d8heg/  - fsfiddle

Comment: where do you define self.errors()?

Comment: i have not defined , i think it is in knockoutjs lib

Comment: no it's not, you need need to specify your own `errors` object. You problably should read into the knockout.validation plugin a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to create validation group:

```
this.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
```

create validation group, the error will be solved